# verify there is a green lock in the url indicating that it is a secure page using Selenium webdriver

Tags: security, selenium-webdriver

How can I verify there is a green lock in the url indicating that it is a secure page, using Selenium webdriver?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Have you tried some code yet? Please show it to us.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you try this:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Now you have `url`, which shows you whether its an `http` or `https`. If its `https` then your connection is secure.

Note: This wont work if you have local ssl certificate, accepted by you.

Comment: I did that as a part of the test case. However, one more point there asks me to check the green lock symbol ad I am struggling with that